# install4j: splash screen doesn't go away

Tags: splash-screen, install4j

I have a splash screen for my launcher, but it doesn't go away. It only disappear when I exit the program.

I want it to go away when the program starts, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if no AWT window is shown. You can call

```
com.install4j.api.launcher.SplashScreen.hide()
```

from your application.

Comment: So it's not possible to hide it directly from the installer?

Comment: This worked for me! I had to add `<installj_root_dir>/resource/i4jruntime.jar` to my classpath to use the library of course.